# Dynamically loading Google Maps API v3 in ExtJS 4

Tags: google-maps-api-3, extjs4

Can you load the Google Maps API in ExtJS 4 after the page has loaded?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
Ext.Loader.loadScriptFile('https://www.google.com/jsapi',function(){
    google.load("maps", "3", {
        other_params:"sensor=false",
        callback : function(){
            // Google Maps are loaded. Place your code here
        }
    });
},Ext.emptyFn,null,false);
```

You can pass more params to the api using:

`other_params: "sensor=false&libraries=places&key=YOUR_API_KEY"`

For more information about the google loader: 
https://developers.google.com/loader/